# How to delete and create graphs in titan/cassandra?

Tags: groovy, cassandra, graph-databases, titan

I am just wondering how to delete an entire graph from titan/cassandra?

I've set up Titan with Elastic Search, Cassandra and Rexster from the website.  I created a simple graph called "graph".  The problem I encountered is I did not realize that

[`Once an index has been created for a key, it can never be removed`](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Titan-Limitations).

So I when experimenting I made a lot of random indexes good and bad.  I tried renaming it in rexster-cassandra-es.xml thinking it would lose the reference but it just continued with a different rexster path.

Also how do you create new databases?  When I started Rexster it just created a database named "graph" for me and I noticed that it allowed you to choose which database to use.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a few things, but the easiest might be to simply shutdown casssandra/elastic search/rexster and just delete the data directories.  Restart it all and get a fresh start.  You could also drop the "titan" key space in cassandra and delete indices in elastic search...the instructions for these approaches would be in the respective documentation for each component.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  This may be a beginner question but do you guys think you will add the ability to add a key index after its property is defined?  That would allow someone the ability to pretty much indiscriminately add data to Titan... and would also be pretty awesome.

Comment: I consider that more than an "awesome" feature....it's an absolute necessity.  It's number 2 on my personal Titan wishlist.  number 1 is clean/simple upgrade/downgrade paths.  Hopefully that's coming soon...at least number 1 is.

Comment: You might also check the Titan test cases for methods to clear a graph as part of unit tests: https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/master/titan-test/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/graphdb/TitanGraphTestCommon.java